# How to use the values in a list in 'for' function

Tags: python, list, for-loop, do-while, variance

I built variances from 'q1' to 'q76'. Now, I want to use these variances to calculate the percentage of “YES” response for all the variables. 
I coded as below:

```
lc = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sas("c:\\Downloads\ps2_hedonic.sas7bdat", format='SAS7BDAT'))
Var = ['q'+str(z) for z in range(1,77)]
yes = 0
no = 0
VS = lc[Var]
for i in VS:
     if i == 1:
        yes += 1
     else:
        no += 1
yes/(yes+no)
```

however, I just got 0 from my code. I guess that maybe I should use 'while' function, but I don't know how to do.

Here is the output of VS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI4OG.png)

Comment: can you show the output of {VS}

Comment: Why do you call these strings 'variances'?

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue without knowing what `lc` is.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of a picture of your variable.

Comment: `i` is not a number but (apparently) a list of numbers since `VS` seems to be a two-dimensional list. You need to iterate through `i` as well.

Comment: Thank you, Tim Pietzcker. Now I got the problem but don't know how to solve it. Maybe I should try 'while' or use another 'for' function?

Comment: We could advise better if only you would tell us what `lc` is.